# IF X and A display area "A1,G20" If X and B display area "A1,G20" but on a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to put together a excel spread sheet for our quarries.
but we have a lot of different pits along two rivers that we collect our raw material from each with its own set of sieve results. now in excel i'm trying to put together a spread sheet that will breakdown the cost of the product depending on the sieve results.
so i have one sheet for each river X & Y with the corresponding pits A, B, C.... Now i also have a sheet that is for lists using data validation,
So i set up the main page that will display the results and has the input options.

What river? Select X or Y
what pit? A, B, C... depending on river

now below this i want to display the sieve tests that are on either sheet X or Y.
How can i pull a whole array through? IF X and A display "" If X and B display "" etc
I need to be able to use these figures for other formula as well.

So first drop down list contains either Whakatane or Waimana
The second deepening on the first list:
**Whatatane**

- Nati Rongo
- X
- Y

**Waimana**

- John Brown's Farm
- A
- B

Now deepening on the second option i have two sheets at the bottom one for Waimana and one for Whakatane with the test results on it (results are 21Rx8C), I want a formula that will pull the correct set of results and display them on the main page where the list options are, all of the test results have the same format.

Comment: Welcome to SU! You might need to provide more details to the question and add more illustrative examples (simplified example with some sample data is usually the best). Currently it is not quite clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I would add images to help show what im trying to do but i cant, i dont have the required rep.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using the `INDIRECT` function. This function allows you to construct a cell reference as text. This means that the sheet name can be part of a text string and can be determined by another cell.

The following formula will link to cell `A1` on the sheet whose name is specified in cell `C2`:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&C2&"'!A1")
```

For example, if cell `C2` contains `X`, the text string inside the parentheses will evaluate to: `'X'!A1`. Note that the quotation marks are necessary in the case that the sheet name contains spaces.

Comment: Still need help, can this even be done ?

Comment: I can't get it working, with that answer, either i cant understand what to do correctly or i didnt describe the situation correctly.